# Salvar o contato, e-mail e telefone ao clicar num link

Tags: javascript, html

Queria saber se isso é possível, pois tenho um cliente que queria fazer isso, eu acredito que não seja. 
Como o título diz, preciso que ao clicar numa imagem (isso no celular, claro) ele salve ou pelo menos vá para a parte do celular de cadastro de contatos.

Alguém já viu algo parecido? Sabe se tem como fazer?

Sei que tem como fazer com a chamada telefônica:

```
<a href="tel:110000000">Telefone</a>
```

Comment: A forma mais prática de fazer isso é utilizando AJAX, leia um pouco sobre e provavelmente conseguirá solucionar esse problema.
Obs: Apenas com PHP é possível também, mas isso seria apenas com reload, então, todos optam pelo AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

**Não é possível**, HTML5 e APIs JavaScript não permitem tão interação, seria legal se existisse uma janela que abrisse perguntando se o usuário gostaria de salvar, mas não existe tal funcionalidade.

No iOS (iPhone) se segurar o touch no link dá a opção <kbd>Add Contacts</kbd>:

[image: Add Contacts iOS]

Creio ser o máximo possível com HTML, no entanto talve Vcard possa ajudar, se criar um documento com a extensão `.vcf` (e o servidor http estiver configurado com o `Content-Type` correto) ou então setar no header de um script dinâmico server-side (como php) o `Content-Type: text/vcard`, com um formato semelhante a este:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
N:Doe;John;;;
FN:John Doe
ORG:Example.com Inc.;
TITLE:Imaginary test person
EMAIL;type=INTERNET;type=WORK;type=pref:johnDoe@example.org
TEL;type=WORK;type=pref:+1 617 555 1212
TEL;type=WORK:+1 (617) 555-1234
TEL;type=CELL:+1 781 555 1212
TEL;type=HOME:+1 202 555 1212
item1.ADR;type=WORK:;;2 Enterprise Avenue;Worktown;NY;01111;USA
item1.X-ABADR:us
item2.ADR;type=HOME;type=pref:;;3 Acacia Avenue;Hoemtown;MA;02222;USA
item2.X-ABADR:us
NOTE:John Doe has a long and varied history\, being documented on more police files that anyone else. Reports of his death are alas numerous.
item3.URL;type=pref:http\://www.example/com/doe
item3.X-ABLabel:_$!<HomePage>!$_
item4.URL:http\://www.example.com/Joe/foaf.df
item4.X-ABLabel:FOAF
item5.X-ABRELATEDNAMES;type=pref:Jane Doe
item5.X-ABLabel:_$!<Friend>!$_
CATEGORIES:Work,Test group
X-ABUID:5AD380FD-B2DE-4261-BA99-DE1D1DB52FBE\:ABPerson
END:VCARD
```

Ao abrir no seu celular é provavel que veja uma tela semelhante a esta:

[image: vcf no iphone]

Então o usuário vai notar o *"Open in Contacts"* (em celulares em Português o texto vai estar em português, não se preocupe)

Fonte: https://www.w3.org/2002/12/cal/vcard-examples/

Comment: Valeu, Gui. Vou testar desta forma que você recomendou.